# html Change in input type=number "available" value. will also change another input type=number "Total"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to copy the change of "available" input number and Add or Subtract it to the "Total"
[image: show availability of item]

- if the person change the "Available" into "3" the "Total" becomes "9".
- if the person change the "Available" into "5" the "Total" becomes "11".

```js
$('#id1').bind('keyup click', function() {
    $('#id2').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" name="total" id="id2" value="10">
<input type="number" name="available" id="id1" value="6">
```

but how can I make this code work

Comment: What is your end goal? To have the `total` equal to the number of `borrowed` plus `available`?

Comment: yes that one exactly. without refreshing the browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the event `input` to capture any changes in that field.

```js
var $borrowed = $('#id3');
var $total = $('#id2');
$('#id1').on('input', function() {
    $total.val(+$(this).val() + +$borrowed.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" name="total" id="id2" value="">
<input type="number" name="borrowed" id="id3" value="6">
<input type="number" name="available" id="id1" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

check your requirement in this link 
https://jsfiddle.net/jedzL38b/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[type=number]').on('input',function(){
   if($(this).attr('id')=='id1')
   {
      $('#id2').val(parseFloat($('#id3').val())+parseFloat($(this).val()))
   }
   })



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" name="total" id="id2" value="">
<input type="number" name="borrowed" id="id3" value="6">
<input type="number" name="available" id="id1" value="">
```